# tweetnacl -- What input does nacl.box.keyPair.fromSecretKey expect?

Tags: javascript, elliptic-curve, x25519, tweet-nacl

I am little bit confused about the API of tweetnacl. Does the function `nacl.box.keyPair.fromSecretKey` except the secretKey argument to be already clamped? Or it is it fine to provide a random byte string? The way I read the code, tweetnacl does the clamping later on, correct? So is the `secretKey` in tweetNacl always a random byte string and the clamping is done in internal library functions?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you don't need to be concerned with 25519 clamping.

The library handles this. You simply need to supply a uniformly random 256-bit byte array.